# Error show insert multiple checked value in codeigneter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Happy New year

please help me senior bro,I can't insert mulityple selected checkbox value into my databse.When i click SUBIT then it show me below error:

```
*Error Number: 1054

Unknown column '0' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `tbl_course_offred` (`0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `user_id`) VALUES ('1', '2', '3', '4', '89', '5', '22', '106', '133', '11')

Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\training\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330 *
```

*Emphasized Text Here*

**Here is my form page:**

```
*<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>user_admin_controller/saveCourses" method="post">

<input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" id="skill[]" value="1" /> Accounting 
<input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" id="skill[]" value="2" /> Accounting Short term 
<input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" id="skill[]" value="3" /> Actuarial Courses
<input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" id="skill[]" value="4" /> Advanced Accounting 
<input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" id="skill[]" value="89" /> Advanced Level 
<input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" id="skill[]" value="5" /> Air hostesses Training
<input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" id="skill[]" value="97" /> AME 
<input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" id="skill[]" value="6" /> Athletic
                                    .
                                    .
                                    .
                                    .
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button"/>
                </form>*
```

**My CI_Controller:**

```
public function saveCourses() {
        $data = $_POST;
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $data = $_POST['skill'];   // here 'SKILL' = tabel Field name
            implode(',', $data);

        }
        $data['user_id'] = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $this->user_admin_model->saveInstituteOfferdCourse($data);  //model function_name: saveInstituteOfferdCourse
        redirect("user_admin_controller/messageCoursesskill");
    }
```

**My CI_MODEL:**

```
public function saveInstituteOfferdCourse($data) {
        $this->db->insert('tbl_course_offred',$data);
     //  return $this->db->affected_rows();

    }
```

please help me how can i solve this problem?

I have another help like:

**Q. How can i display data without ',' comma  view page ?**

please please help me senior..

Regards,

Comment: Your table is missing the field `0`?

Comment: @Rashedkhan what are the columns in the table tbl_course_offred ?

Comment: what are your table fields

Answer (score 2):

There are so many flaws in your code.

1) First, do not keep element ID as an array.. Give some unique id

2) You didnt mention table field name in the insert query..

3) You made a mistake. You treated your element name as table field name..

Comment: I think i can't do it myself.So,please can you clearly write this all code.

Answer (score 0):

Your table has no `column` as `0` . Check your **Table Structure** again.

As depicted by the Query - Your table `tbl_course_offred` has `columns` as `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,user_id]`

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_course_offred` (`0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `user_id`) VALUES ('1', '2', '3', '4', '89', '5', '22', '106', '133', '11')
```

But clearly from the given error there is no such column.

Paste the output of following command (mysql terminal)

> DESCRIBE tbl_course_offred